# Why request is not posted on unit test while it works by simple API call?

Tags: unit-testing, flask

This is my code:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from myProject import app
import unittest


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_login(self):
        response = app.test_client().post('/login', data={})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run this script I get the following error:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_login (__main__.TestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_login.py", line 16, in test_login
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.096s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

---

**EDIT1:**

In `app.py` file I have:

```
from flask_restful import Api
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class myProjectApp(object):
    def setup(self):
         api.add_resource(Login, '/login')
```

I've got 404. But simple API call to `/login` works as expected. My app in on port 5000 if it is related on anyway. Is there something here I am missing?

---

**EDIT2:**

It seems that testing flask restful api with unit test is different, as working with built-in `route` decorator works perfectly and unit test works. How should I test flask restful API?

Answer (score 0):

As I was using `Api(app)` which is an external library for restful web service, routes were unreachable. I called setup function inside of unittest method to initialize the `Api` routes. Now it works as expected:

```
myApp = myProjectApp()
self.app = myApp.setup()
```

The setup method contains:

```
def setup(self):
        api.add_resource(Login, '/login')
        .
        .
        .
```